# SQL query to laravel query builder - convert

Tags: php, sql, laravel

How can I translate this query to Laravel query build.

```
SELECT stocks.* FROM stocks, stocksUnits WHERE stocks.name LIKE '%eg%' OR (stocksUnits.code = stocks.unit and stocksUnits.comment LIKE '%eg%')
```

example:

```
$datas =  Stocks::where('code','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out.

```
   $stocks = DB::table(DB::raw('stocks as stock', 'stockUnits as stockUnit'))
     ->select('stock.*')
     ->where('stock.name','LIKE',"%eg%")
     ->orWhere(function($query)
     {
        $query->where('stockUnits.code','=','stock.unit')
        ->where('stockUnits.comment','like','%eg%');
     }
    )
```

Thanks.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stockUnit.code' in 'where clause

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 DB::table("stocks, stocksunits")
->select("stocks.*")
->where("stocks.name", "like", %eg%)
->where(DB::raw("(stocksunits.code = stocks.unit and stocksunits.comment like '%eg%')"))
->get();
```

or

```
DB::table('stocks')
->crossJoin('stocksUnits'
->select('stocks.*')
->where('stocks.name','like','%eg%')
->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->where('stocksUnits.code','=',DB::raw('stocks.unit'))
        ->where('stocksUnits.comment','like','%eg%');
})
->get();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.